# Creating scatter plot class or group wise

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, correlation

Im using ggstatsplot's ggscatterstats function to calculate correlation between various clinical parameters and then plotting them. For example [image: age scatter]

here my variables are age and WBC. This is taking all the data points irrespective of the class they belong. I would like to do the same with each FAB classification that is present in my data.

```
dat <- merge_clinical_class_TMB %>% select(FAB,AGE,Wbc,Platelet,HB,PB_Blasts,BM_Blasts,TMB_NONSYNONYMOUS)
df2 <- dat
library(ggstatsplot)
ggscatterstats(
  df2,
  x = AGE,
  y = Wbc,
  type = "np" # try the "robust" correlation too! It might be even better here
  #, marginal.type = "boxplot"
)
```

My dataframe looks like this

```
head(df2)
  FAB AGE Wbc Platelet HB PB_Blasts BM_Blasts TMB_NONSYNONYMOUS
1  M4  50  17      231 10        88        52         0.3000000
2  M3  61   1       90 10        44         0         0.4333333
3  M3  30   6      114 11        82         6         0.2333333
4  M0  77  92      105  9        67        56         0.4000000
5  M1  46  29       90  9        90        81         0.5666667
6  M1  68   3       63  8        91        55         0.9000000
```

My data

```
dput(df2)
structure(list(FAB = structure(c(5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 
3L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 
2L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
4L), .Label = c("M0", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", 
"nc"), class = "factor"), AGE = c(50L, 61L, 30L, 77L, 46L, 68L, 
23L, 64L, 76L, 81L, 25L, 78L, 39L, 49L, 57L, 63L, 62L, 52L, 76L, 
64L, 65L, 61L, 44L, 31L, 64L, 33L, 55L, 50L, 64L, 59L, 59L, 77L, 
33L, 48L, 35L, 66L, 67L, 51L, 74L, 51L, 64L, 77L, 63L, 37L, 57L, 
53L, 62L, 39L, 72L, 66L, 51L, 51L, 18L, 63L, 54L, 75L, 40L, 60L, 
76L, 33L, 63L, 53L, 75L, 67L, 66L, 77L, 64L, 76L, 51L, 42L, 51L, 
59L, 43L, 45L, 60L, 47L, 68L, 24L, 48L, 73L, 60L, 44L, 71L, 25L, 
60L, 57L, 55L, 69L, 42L, 42L, 45L, 50L, 41L, 21L, 50L, 69L, 76L, 
70L, 27L, 76L, 65L, 48L, 59L, 69L, 81L, 22L, 61L, 51L, 63L, 61L, 
22L, 73L, 49L, 41L, 47L, 54L, 44L, 55L, 83L, 78L, 59L, 57L, 57L, 
88L, 43L, 71L, 62L, 75L, 62L, 58L, 65L, 66L, 60L, 35L, 76L, 72L, 
35L, 73L, 67L, 70L, 48L, 65L, 41L, 52L, 67L, 58L, 34L, 60L, 55L, 
56L, 61L, 31L, 71L, 56L, 57L, 60L, 57L, 58L, 79L, 55L, 34L, 76L, 
82L, 67L, 67L, 54L, 53L, 71L, 61L, 30L, 50L, 35L, 29L, 45L, 38L, 
81L, 31L, 75L, 67L, 29L, 51L, 40L, 32L, 57L, 25L, 63L, 75L, 25L, 
68L, 62L, 25L, 31L, 68L, 45L, 61L, 35L, 22L, 23L, 21L, 53L), 
    Wbc = c(17L, 1L, 6L, 92L, 29L, 3L, 32L, 117L, 62L, 91L, 34L, 
    10L, 2L, 57L, 88L, 77L, 75L, 4L, 15L, 1L, 3L, 86L, 9L, 137L, 
    132L, 3L, 22L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 12L, 40L, 26L, 116L, 53L, 112L, 
    2L, 42L, 32L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 17L, 19L, 14L, 3L, 119L, 5L, 3L, 
    79L, 104L, 3L, 35L, 77L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 46L, 2L, 
    6L, 31L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 34L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 12L, 4L, 29L, 12L, 
    12L, 60L, 224L, 33L, 2L, 7L, 14L, 5L, 11L, 47L, 5L, 31L, 
    6L, 11L, 38L, 5L, 7L, 134L, 93L, 3L, 10L, 3L, 48L, 90L, 297L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 115L, 35L, 50L, 18L, 62L, 52L, 15L, 12L, 
    48L, 81L, 13L, 35L, 28L, 78L, 17L, 30L, 99L, 20L, 3L, 172L, 
    6L, 28L, 98L, 59L, 101L, 68L, 2L, 2L, 43L, 4L, 38L, 34L, 
    59L, 37L, 1L, 111L, 49L, 43L, 298L, 26L, 47L, 14L, 16L, 114L, 
    203L, 8L, 133L, 1L, 31L, 3L, 68L, 3L, 20L, 19L, 73L, 20L, 
    5L, 1L, 15L, 45L, 68L, 88L, 36L, 10L, 23L, 1L, 72L, 1L, 2L, 
    40L, 12L, 13L, 7L, 46L, 2L, 64L, NA, 5L, 103L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 
    16L, 29L, 1L, 99L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 115L, 27L, 8L, 1L), 
    Platelet = c(231L, 90L, 114L, 105L, 90L, 63L, 38L, 100L, 
    32L, 32L, 23L, 98L, 215L, 14L, 56L, 19L, 110L, 22L, 85L, 
    42L, 16L, 22L, 50L, 42L, 15L, 61L, 65L, 50L, 134L, 102L, 
    57L, 29L, 111L, 50L, 44L, 34L, 28L, 232L, 42L, 58L, 27L, 
    86L, 23L, 38L, 76L, 108L, 52L, 175L, 52L, 132L, 23L, 143L, 
    30L, 41L, 9L, 21L, 95L, 59L, 79L, 38L, 11L, 68L, 22L, 141L, 
    168L, 70L, 41L, 21L, 25L, 35L, 14L, 20L, 67L, 116L, 45L, 
    57L, 8L, 34L, 32L, 60L, 93L, 145L, 48L, 33L, 50L, 129L, 9L, 
    61L, 176L, 12L, 53L, 136L, 40L, 73L, 27L, 12L, 166L, 30L, 
    87L, 40L, 94L, 52L, 23L, 127L, 39L, 57L, 35L, 21L, 148L, 
    25L, 149L, 64L, 351L, 71L, 53L, 22L, 35L, 31L, 46L, 85L, 
    18L, 80L, 62L, 156L, 32L, 50L, 69L, 31L, 20L, 57L, 142L, 
    37L, 79L, 66L, 21L, 31L, 88L, 11L, 15L, 82L, 53L, 76L, 51L, 
    68L, 64L, 55L, 40L, 90L, 37L, 45L, 36L, 52L, 86L, 88L, 35L, 
    174L, 28L, 121L, 131L, 17L, 152L, 52L, 30L, 79L, 79L, 87L, 
    30L, 44L, 140L, 59L, 58L, 19L, 29L, 156L, 19L, 61L, 36L, 
    11L, 71L, 13L, 45L, 34L, 39L, 82L, 18L, 43L, 118L, 32L, 73L, 
    15L, 60L, 208L, 96L, 257L, 61L, 12L, 32L, 23L, 52L, 46L), 
    HB = c(10L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
    10L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 8L, 6L, 
    10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 
    13L, 9L, 8L, 12L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
    12L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
    10L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 
    9L, 10L, 12L, NA, 10L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 
    8L, 10L, 9L, 12L, 11L, 8L, 13L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 10L, 9L, 
    10L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 
    9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 
    9L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 13L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 
    9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 7L, 13L, 14L, 
    12L, 8L, 12L, 8L, 9L), PB_Blasts = c(88L, 44L, 82L, 67L, 
    90L, 91L, 59L, 60L, 48L, 98L, 53L, 40L, 75L, 81L, 90L, 57L, 
    46L, 67L, 74L, 61L, 99L, 73L, 74L, 83L, 72L, 33L, 35L, 70L, 
    85L, 61L, 95L, 80L, 71L, 83L, 90L, 90L, 50L, 64L, 51L, 93L, 
    95L, 75L, 80L, 52L, 61L, 72L, 65L, 83L, 45L, 32L, 85L, 73L, 
    86L, 82L, 30L, 48L, 47L, 58L, 78L, 100L, 81L, 82L, 40L, 89L, 
    70L, 47L, 80L, 73L, 62L, 88L, 57L, 70L, 40L, 56L, 86L, 37L, 
    90L, 77L, 75L, 37L, 94L, 86L, 97L, 72L, 87L, 40L, 52L, 60L, 
    68L, 40L, 95L, 81L, 92L, 90L, 90L, 42L, 37L, 84L, 77L, 99L, 
    83L, 65L, 79L, 82L, 46L, 94L, 71L, 39L, 62L, 95L, 55L, 11L, 
    51L, 42L, 77L, 72L, 39L, 69L, 75L, 70L, 75L, 52L, 91L, 33L, 
    87L, 55L, 72L, 76L, 85L, 79L, 79L, 81L, 50L, 81L, 33L, 88L, 
    34L, 90L, 69L, 32L, 92L, 90L, 47L, 75L, 30L, 59L, 57L, 62L, 
    54L, 60L, 89L, 82L, 90L, 90L, 64L, 89L, 43L, 58L, 58L, 97L, 
    71L, 91L, 53L, 75L, 85L, 67L, 86L, 70L, 43L, 86L, 74L, 87L, 
    0L, 0L, 86L, 53L, 63L, 41L, 76L, 45L, 85L, 0L, 94L, 6L, 91L, 
    0L, 2L, 93L, 85L, 82L, 56L, 40L, 48L, 0L, 14L, 90L, 71L, 
    51L, 91L, 42L), BM_Blasts = c(52L, 0L, 6L, 56L, 81L, 55L, 
    0L, 0L, 88L, 37L, 87L, 6L, 4L, 48L, 84L, 70L, 53L, 18L, 82L, 
    5L, 34L, 68L, 5L, 6L, 90L, 0L, 67L, 0L, 22L, 12L, 0L, 2L, 
    14L, 3L, 18L, 7L, 17L, 79L, 0L, 40L, 0L, 8L, 71L, 33L, 17L, 
    41L, 65L, 53L, 0L, 11L, 85L, 2L, 90L, 39L, 0L, 54L, 23L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 97L, 42L, 48L, 61L, 6L, 0L, 46L, 55L, 10L, 2L, 
    0L, 48L, 39L, 37L, 43L, 0L, 91L, 76L, 41L, 16L, 30L, 17L, 
    54L, 50L, 65L, 0L, 59L, 22L, 51L, 16L, 6L, 10L, 90L, 72L, 
    0L, 32L, 0L, 49L, 88L, 98L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 94L, 55L, 
    39L, 9L, 86L, 70L, 11L, 5L, 74L, 79L, 90L, 83L, 57L, 74L, 
    28L, 17L, 4L, 91L, 0L, 91L, 50L, 49L, 80L, 22L, 64L, 84L, 
    12L, 14L, 86L, 6L, 18L, 40L, 0L, 61L, 6L, 87L, 0L, 62L, 51L, 
    6L, 72L, 59L, 29L, 24L, 96L, 0L, 53L, 13L, 45L, 61L, 56L, 
    35L, 10L, 0L, 8L, 58L, 16L, 25L, 10L, 3L, 71L, 52L, 67L, 
    32L, 88L, 10L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 97L, 7L, 45L, 0L, 49L, 9L, 85L, 
    0L, 70L, 91L, 7L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 32L, 11L, 71L, 0L, 48L, 0L, 
    14L, 7L, 90L, 63L, 83L, 29L), TMB_NONSYNONYMOUS = c(0.3, 
    0.433333333333, 0.233333333333, 0.4, 0.566666666667, 0.9, 
    0.3, 0.133333333333, 0.4, 0.3, 0.233333333333, 0.5, 0.266666666667, 
    0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.266666666667, 0.333333333333, 0.4, 0.4, 0.566666666667, 
    0.0333333333333, 0.166666666667, 0.1, 0.166666666667, 0.266666666667, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.466666666667, 0.0666666666667, 0.266666666667, 
    0.266666666667, 0.0333333333333, 0.1, 0.133333333333, 0.0333333333333, 
    0.5, 0.6, 0.0333333333333, 0.1, 0.0333333333333, 0.333333333333, 
    0.433333333333, 0.2, 0.466666666667, 0.2, 0.0333333333333, 
    0.733333333333, 0.2, 0.233333333333, 0.233333333333, 0.3, 
    0.133333333333, 0, 0.3, 0.333333333333, 0.333333333333, 0.266666666667, 
    0.533333333333, 0.2, 0.533333333333, 0.466666666667, 0.533333333333, 
    0.0333333333333, 0.3, 0.5, 0.333333333333, 0.266666666667, 
    0.5, 0.333333333333, 0.0666666666667, 0.466666666667, 0.333333333333, 
    0.266666666667, 0.7, 0.433333333333, 0.166666666667, 0.0666666666667, 
    0.233333333333, 0.5, 0.0333333333333, 0.2, 0.433333333333, 
    0.433333333333, 0.4, 0.233333333333, 0.0666666666667, 0.233333333333, 
    0.466666666667, 0.0666666666667, 0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 
    0.433333333333, 0.566666666667, 0.2, 0.0333333333333, 0.533333333333, 
    0.566666666667, 0.3, 0.466666666667, 0.566666666667, 0.0333333333333, 
    0.4, 0.0666666666667, 0.633333333333, 0.4, 0.466666666667, 
    0.466666666667, 0.3, 0.5, 0.0333333333333, 0.333333333333, 
    0.333333333333, 0.266666666667, 0.366666666667, 0.666666666667, 
    0.333333333333, 0.533333333333, 0.466666666667, 0.6, 0.333333333333, 
    0.4, 0.266666666667, 0.366666666667, 0.2, 0.0333333333333, 
    0.266666666667, 0.3, 0.166666666667, 0.4, 0.566666666667, 
    0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0666666666667, 0.366666666667, 0, 0.4, 0.0333333333333, 
    0.1, 0.0666666666667, 0.5, 0.3, 0.466666666667, 0.0333333333333, 
    0.4, 0.1, 0.0666666666667, 0.766666666667, 0.5, 0.466666666667, 
    0.333333333333, 0.4, 0.333333333333, 0.4, 0.266666666667, 
    0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.166666666667, 0.2, 0, 0.5, 0.166666666667, 
    0.533333333333, 0.233333333333, 0.166666666667, 0.133333333333, 
    0.0666666666667, 0.4, 0.333333333333, 0.133333333333, 0.4, 
    0.233333333333, 0.466666666667, 0.366666666667, 0.266666666667, 
    0.266666666667, 0.266666666667, 0.4, 0.2, 0.166666666667, 
    0.4, 0.333333333333, 0.166666666667, 0.266666666667, 0.1, 
    0.333333333333, 0.733333333333, 0.466666666667, 0.466666666667, 
    0.2, 0.1, 1.13333333333, 0.2, 0.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-200L))
```

**Objective** I would like to do the same with various `FAB`I have FAB label from `M0` to `M7` I would like to ignore `nc`

So for each FAB label I would like to see the correlation for example if I have to take the M0 class then I would like to see their Age vs Wbc correlation and similarly for other FAB class as well. Is it possible to do these in ggstataplot as I don't see for correlation any such functionality there .

Simple way is I can subset them and do the same like M0 ,M1, M2 etc etc but that is a long process can I split the FAB column and pass it to the library?

I would like to know other ways to do the above and plot the same

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: I don't think the linear regression model / formula are quite right for this data set, since `Wbc` has a large positive skew. You might want to consider transforming the data to get a more realistic model. Perhaps using something like `Wbc^0.2`?

Comment: `Wbc^0.2` yes that thing I got it after seeing paper who build clinical models transforming those counts thanks for giving this point ...since they collect absolute counts i was not sure how to use or go ahead

Comment: i did what you suggested the reported p value is nearly identical ...should i go for log transform ?

Comment: The log transform does seem to be used in the literature, and it certainly seems to give better model residuals than untransformed wbc count.

Comment: thank you for the valuable comments I will try that downstream with gene expression and will possibly update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** We could also use the built in function see comments:
Many thanks to @Indrajeet Patil: https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/articles/web_only/ggscatterstats.html#grouped-analysis-with-grouped_ggscatterstats
To subset FAB we use filter:

```
## for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

## plot
grouped_ggscatterstats(
  ## arguments relevant for ggscatterstats
  data = df2 %>% filter(as.integer(FAB)<5),
  x = AGE,
  y = Wbc,
  grouping.var = FAB,
  type = "r",
  # ggtheme = ggthemes::theme_tufte(),
  ## arguments relevant for combine_plots
  annotation.args = list(
    title = "Relationship between Wbc and Age",
    caption = "Source: stackoverflow"
  ),
  plotgrid.args = list(nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
)
```

[image]

**First answer:**
We could do something like this:
write a function and pass the data frame + the column FAB value:

```
library(ggstatsplot)


my_function <- function(df, x){
 ggscatterstats(
    df %>% filter(FAB == x),
    x = AGE,
    y = Wbc,
    type = "np" # try the "robust" correlation too! It might be even better here
    #, marginal.type = "boxplot"
  )
}

M0 <- my_function(df2, "M0")
M1 <- my_function(df2, "M1")
M2 <- my_function(df2, "M2")
M3 <- my_function(df2, "M3")
.
.
.


library(patchwork)
(M0 / M1 | M2 / M3)
```

[image]

Comment: {ggstatsplot} already provides a way to do this using `grouped_ggscatterstats()` function: https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/articles/web_only/ggscatterstats.html#grouped-analysis-with-grouped_ggscatterstats

Comment: This is fantastic. I will add it to the anser.

Comment: wow i didn't see the function thank you for again another improved answer ..

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil is possible to generate the tables for the comparison that is made by ggstatsplot's function whatever I have used which can be used as supplementary tables for journal  as I have made quite a large no of comparison and figures which only a few will go ..so is there a function in your library to do that?

Comment: @PesKchan Nope.; it's a purely a visualization library. You can have a look at this function and see if it can be useful for you: https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/reference/extract_stats.html